# How to write more than one sigma notation (sigma notation not inside the text), but still aligned?

Tags: equations, alignment, scientific-notation

I want to write sum notation like the picture below, but the sum notation is not inside the text. I already tried, but the sum notation is still inside the text. I use the code below. What should I do?

```
\begin{align*}
Q_{n+1} &= \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} R_i \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+\Sigma_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right) \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+(n-1)\frac{1}{n-1}\,\Sigma_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right) \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{n} (R_n+(n-1) Q_n) \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{n} (R_n+nQ_n-Q_n) \nonumber \\
&= Q_n+\frac{1}{n} \left[R_n-Q_n\right] \end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you after the following:

[image]

In LaTeX is for summation defined special symbol `\sum`. Considering it for wrong used `\Sigma` you will get showed result.

Complete MWE (Minimal Working Example) after removing all clutter and make parenthesis more consistent (equal height), is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
Q_{n+1} &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} R_i \\
    & = \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right)  \\
    & = \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+(n-1)\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right)  \\
    & = \left.\frac{1}{n} \middle(R_n+(n-1) Q_n\right)     \\
    & = \left.\frac{1}{n} \middle(R_n+nQ_n-Q_n\right)      \\
    & = Q_n + \left.\frac{1}{n} \middle[R_n-Q_n\right] 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**Addednum:**
However, if I correct only wron used symbols, than  YOUR code fragment is:

```
\begin{align*}
Q_{n+1} &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} R_i \\
    & = \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right)  \\
    & = \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+(n-1)\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right)  \\
    & = \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+(n-1) Q_n\right)     \\
    & = \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+nQ_n-Q_n\right)      \\
    & = Q_n + \frac{1}{n} \left[R_n-Q_n\right]
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Similar approach is done in @egreg answer. There you can find more extensive explanation concerning your code too. He also siggest t remove all `\left` and `ight` mechanism in the last three equations since without them the result is equal.

Comment: thank you so much for your help

Comment: @LouisaV, does answer solve your problem? If yes, you may consider to accept them (by clicking on check mark at top left side of the answer) any by this inform members of site, that your problem is solved.

Comment: Why complicating things with `\left.` and `\middle`?

Comment: @Zarko okay done, thank you for your information, I'm still a newbie with this site.

Comment: @egreg, ro show OP how to make all parenthesis in equations equal high   if he will stick with `\left(` ...`\right)` mechanism.  That there are another possibility -- use of manual adjusting their heights by `\big(`, `\Big`, `\bigg` , etc. -- OP can found in the other  answers.  I just replicate showed image on the way how OP try to do.

Comment: There is no need to have the parentheses as high as the outer fraction.

Comment: @egreg, you are right. There is not need to have equal height of  parentheses. I'm aware of this.  Now is to late to correct my answer since this is already covered by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need `\sum` and not `\Sigma` (which is the command to get a plain capital sigma, not the summation operator).

You can also make the input simpler by removing `\nonumber`, because `align*` doesn't add equation numbers.

And you can make the output more attractive by not using `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Better output
\begin{align*}
Q_{n+1}
  &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} R_i \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} \biggl(R_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\biggr) \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} \biggl(R_n+(n-1)\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\biggr) \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} (R_n+(n-1) Q_n) \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} (R_n+nQ_n-Q_n) \\
  &= Q_n+\frac{1}{n} [R_n-Q_n]
\end{align*}

With \verb|\left| and \verb|\right|
\begin{align*}
Q_{n+1}
  &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} R_i \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} \left(R_n+(n-1)\frac{1}{n-1}\,\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} R_i\right) \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} (R_n+(n-1) Q_n) \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} (R_n+nQ_n-Q_n) \\
  &= Q_n+\frac{1}{n} \left[R_n-Q_n\right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]